# Difference between setting text on a text view

Tags: android

What is the difference between

```
textView.setText("hello")
```

and

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTxtTimer.setText(time);
    }
});
```

If i have to set text in a loop which is beneficial for me.

Comment: ok thank you, but that was not my question

Comment: if you are trying to set dynamic text that keeps changing after certain duration on regular interval u can go for something like runnable... but for one time setting of text u can use directly..

Comment: Somme times you are modifyng text dynamicaly then thread will miss that thing , so that we will choose a os thread to updated it .

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
   public void run() {
 mTxtTimer.setText(time);
 }
 });
```

This is creating new child thread of working in UI(parent thread)
This will run in the UI thread, no matter who calls it.